# JMeter Result Analysis - How to determine which point of the thread group starts failing when the test is still running?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

Recently I ran an API Load Test of only 10 thread groups with 75 loops with ramp up 1s. I saved the test results in CSV and able to generate the [HTML Dashboard report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

But for me, the HTML Dashboard report won't show enough information, I was expecting to know at which point the thread groups start failing.

Question here, how to determine which point of the thread group starts failing when the test is still running? Is this possible to do so in this free JMeter license?

Please find the link of my JMeter HTML report [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X8dreLpswc7GynbtN2Wn0r0UGLmXgaAu/view?usp=sharing), you may refer and try to view the HTML report there. I also have the View Results Tree csv file uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l3ZeRL0yfg2wr2xQMpsEWiHCSd-3qRqa/view?usp=sharing) in case you want to import and view my test results in JMeter View Result Tree listener.

Anyone can suggest what is the best way to determine this?

Thank you and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Reporting Dashboard can be generated only **after** the test execution

The options to monitor response times/throughput/number of failures while the test is running are in:

1. When you launch JMeter in [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) it prints some basic statistics into the [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))

   [image]
2. It's possible to configure JMeter's Backend Listener and use 3rd-party solutions like [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to [see real-time statictics while the test is running](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)

   [image]

   [image]
3. Your can run your JMeter test using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as the wrapper, it provides interactive reports in the STDOUT:

   [image]

   and in the browser if you run Taurus with [`-report` switch](https://gettaurus.org/docs/BlazemeterReporter/):

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what you mean by the **TG failing**. Keep in mind that Thread Groups don't "fail", threads do, by returning an error (for example).